# How to get URL path data automation to fill in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to get the data of URL to automation fill in textbox

For Example :[www.example.com/info.asp?uid=123](http://www.example.com/info.asp?uid=123)
when i click [www.example.com/info.asp?uid=123](http://www.example.com/info.asp?uid=123)

example.com Page show:
the User id:[123]

```html
<form action="/info">
  <label for="uid">User id:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

anybody can give advise or idea for handle a automation  fill in column. thanks!

Comment: `<%= Request.QueryString["uid"] %>` or `@Request.QueryString["uid"]`

Comment: it is work. thanks bro